How to install R package hsdar?
I need to use a discontinued R package called hsdar. It seems to be impossble to install, I have tried installing an older version of R to run it, but no version seems to accept the package.
I've also tried this:
hsdar <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/hsdar/hsdar_1.0.4.tar.gz"
install.packages(hsdar, repos=NULL, type="source")

, and to download an older version of the package directly to my computer and install it from there.
In every case, the program only announces that the package is not available for this version of R. It also says that the package rgdal which is needed for this is also discontinued. Is there any way to use/install the hsdar package?

Does this work? devtools::install_git("https://github.com/cran/hsdar/")

thank you, unfortunately it does not. The error I get is: "Error: Failed to install 'hsdar' from Git:
! System command 'Rcmd.exe' failed"
